# Qual a diferença entre o algoritmo KNeighborsClassifier e Nearest Neighbors?

Tags: classificação, machine-learning

Eu conheço o conceito dos algoritmos de vizinhança porém me deparei com duas implementações na biblioteca Sklearn, sendo elas [NearestNeighbors](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/neighbors.html) e [K-NearestNeighbors](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier.html), porém não consegui entender a diferença, é algo relacionado a definição do parâmetro K?

Answer (score 0):

O K-Neareast Neighbors (KNN) espera como entrada uma matriz com os pontos e seus respectivos rótulos, ou seja, é aprendizado supervisionado pois as informações de entrada já estão classificadas, a contribuição do KNN é dado uma nova informação ou ponto, determinar a qual classe ele pertence, ou seja, qual rótulo já conhecido ele vai receber. O Nearest Neighbors atua sem ter nenhum rótulo prévio dos dados, ou seja, aprendizado não supervisionado, sendo essa então a principal diferença.

Obtive a resposta mas vou deixar o tópico caso alguém tenha a dúvida também.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: Olá @Carlos, obrigado por compartilhar seu entendimento com a comunidade... Caso você tenha alguma referencia/link/etc.. que possa ajudar a reforçar sua resposta / auxiliar outros a chegar ao mesmo entendimento você pode adicionar clicando em [edit]. =D